# Load more Items in the middle of recycler

Tags: android

I'm having trouble building a twitter style load more button in the middle of my recyclerview. I'm currently working with a syncAdapter to fetch new data before inserting them into a db. I also have a ContentProvider and i'm using a Loader which is a CursorLoader to update the recycler_view's adapter.

When the syncAdapter fetches newer data than what exists in the app and there is more data available between **the last of the new items** fetched and the **previous top item** I want to show a LoadMore button in between.

My would-be logic for activating the loadMore button in my adapter is if the last row id of the newly fetched data set doesn't exist in the db. But the problem is I don't know where to perform this logic.

I can't make it in `onLoadFinished` because it is called after the new data is inserted, so I can't check the incoming data against the old data there, because by then the id of the last row in the incoming data set has already been written to the db.

I've thought of making the check while unparsing the incoming json before inserting to the db. I can check if the last id received exists in the db there, and know if a load more button is warranted, but letting the adapter know from there seems non-trivial. Since data is fetched on another thread(syncadapter or a service I've got), i'd have to write the fact that loadmore exists between two rows in SharedPreferences or send a broadcast. Is there a more elegant way of doing this, maybe i've missed something.

I'm open to suggestions.